# JavaScript on body click work 1 time

Tags: javascript, click, alert

This is my script - 
my script alert when someone touch on any place on the page .
I am trying to execute alert only one time and not on every click.

This is the code i built which alert any time .

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var click_count = 0;

if (click_count == 0){

$('body').click(function(){

  alert();
  var click_count  = 1;
});



}
});
```

Comment: Place your `if` statement inside `click` callback

Comment: You can also remove the event listenter all together using `$("body").off("click")` [jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: jquery provide .one() function for such case

Answer (score 1):

You have your `if` in the wrong place. You want it **inside** the click handler (the code that runs when the click occurs), not outside it. You also need to remove the `var` from `var click_count = 1;` so you 're using the one declared in the `ready` callback, not the one declared in the `click` handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var click_count = 0;
    $('body').on("click", function() {
        if (click_count == 0) {
            alert("Hi there");
            click_count = 1;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
Testing 1 2 3
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(Here's a runnable version for mobiles where Stack Snippets aren't rendered: http://output.jsbin.com/taropelopu)

**But**, rather than using `click_count`, I'd suggest removing the event handler after the first click. You could do that with [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/), but jQuery even has a function specifically for adding a handler you remove the first time it's called: [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) (rather than [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').one("click", function() {
        alert("Hi there");
    });
});
```

```html
Testing 1 2 3
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(Runnable version for devices where Stack Snippets don't render: http://output.jsbin.com/wivoroluzu)

Comment: @user2256727: Both of the above work just fine on mobile devices.

Comment: @user2256727: If you mean *stack snippets* don't work on mobile devices, that's true (or rather, they're not rendered as runnable). The code is fine, though, if you actually try it. I've added links to JSBin since it's mobile-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

With plain JavaScript you can do

```js
let clicked = false;

const clickOnce = () =>  {
  if (!clicked) {
    alert('clicked');
    clicked = true;
  }
};

document.body.addEventListener('click', clickOnce);
```

```html
some body content
```

And you don't even need a `clicked` variable to store the state. Just remove the `event listener` once it is triggered.

```js
const clickOnce = () =>  {
  alert('clicked');
  document.body.removeEventListener('click', clickOnce)
};

document.body.addEventListener('click', clickOnce);
```

```html
some body content
```

Comment: @user2256727 if it is for mobile version, try changing the `click` handler to `mouseenter`